# Can I use adapters without having ListViews?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-custom-view

I receive lots of data from the backend that I need to display in 2 sections of my app in different ways, such as drawing real time graphs. 1 of the sections in question is a rectangle, that is just an elaborate scrollbar (drag the frame you see in the image below to change the set of channels currently displayed).

Without going too much into detail, I have a list of channels and for each channel I generate a line inside that rectangle. It should end up looking like this:

[image]

The color of each line also depends on the type and state of each channel so each line has a bit of logic, meaning it must be a view instead of just a png. That rectangle cannot be scrolled, it's a static view. So I was thinking, is there a way to use an adapter (Something like an ArrayAdapter) without a ListView? I want to have a LinearLayout and inside that LinearLayout I want a line to be created for each channel object inside the List. Should I just make a foreach loop?

Comment: `ListView` and `ListAdapter` have been obsolete for several years. They were replaced by `RecyclerView` and `RecyclerView.Adapter`. For this case, since your content is not scrollable, a `LinearLayout` (or a `Row()` in Compose UI) seems fine. An adapter seems unnecessary, as those are for cases where you need scrolling and need to be able to create the visual representations of a large data set on the fly as the user scrolls.

Comment: Just a little clarfication...`android.widget.ListAdapter` is obsolete but `androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter` is not.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hey, thank you for your answer. I'd like to clarify; is it correct that in this case a for each loop would be appropriate to fill the LinearLayout with Views? Might be a bad question but I was taught to avoid for loops at all costs.

Comment: "is it correct that in this case a for each loop would be appropriate to fill the LinearLayout with Views?" -- for your approach, yes, as I do not know how else you would do it. "I was taught to avoid for loops at all costs" -- that was very imprecise advice that you were given.

Comment: For loops are great and a key part of handling anything at scale. You may have misinterpreted the advice or had a very poor teacher.

Answer (score 0):

> "`ListView` and `ListAdapter` have been obsolete for several years. They were replaced by `RecyclerView` and `RecyclerView.Adapter`. For this case, since your content is not scrollable, a `LinearLayout` (or a `Row()` in Compose UI) seems fine. An adapter seems unnecessary, as those are for cases where you need scrolling and need to be able to create the visual representations of a large data set on the fly as the user scrolls." -
> @CommonsWare

In the case above, the appropriate solution would be to `for each` loop the `List` to create and add `Views` to a `LinearLayout`. Adapters are unnecessary, since in this scenario scrolling is unwanted.